# Appropriate loader error on index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm stuck on this same error and I need fresh eyes for help.... I'm confused on the "appropriate loader". I was thinking this was from an improper regular expression in the webpack file. I checked the babel docs and this [issue](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/173) for guidance.

This is the error...

ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:16)

You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src

This is my **src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import App from './Components/App'
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [["react-transform",{
      "transforms": [{
        "transform": "react-transform-hmr",
        "imports": ["react"],
        "locals": ["module"]
      }]
    }]]
    }
  }
}
```

**webpack.dev.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src")]
      }
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    inline: true,
    hot: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: 'src/index.html'}),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
}
```

and my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "webpack-starter-kit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "starter files for basic development and production using React, Babel, Webpack",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --mode=development",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production"
  },
  "author": "Kevin Turney",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.7",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.4",
    "webpack": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.15",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share screenshot of an error? I would like to see a pointer where it crashed. Thanks

Comment: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7386478/39262013-2fca6cd0-488c-11e8-8a2d-e466cf1b72cb.png

Comment: Try to provide your webpack config via `--config webpack.dev.config.js`. It might be because of new webpack version that supports zero config builds and actually creates default config with entry: src/index.js if it cannot find webpack.config.js in your directory.

Comment: I added that to the scripts in package.json, **"--config webpack.dev.config.js --mode=development"**, invalid option error.

Comment: CORRECTION: scripts in package.json, **"webpack --config webpack.dev.config.js --progress --mode=development"**, compiles but now I have no dev server. So the error is emanating from a devServer problem.

Comment: Here is a [screenshot](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7386478/39265902-8193eece-4896-11e8-8658-0ad8542cbe8a.png)

Comment: When I added **"dev":"webpack-dev-server --open --mode=development"** and ran npm run dev, the error appears.

Comment: That's strange. `webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.config.js --mode=development` should work. I can recommend reinstalling webpack-dev-server. You might have some alpha version or something.
Try to launch `webpack-dev-server --help` to get info about possible options (there should be `--config`).

Comment: I did npm update and am using **"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3"**